# Dart: Access inherited property or method from generic class

Tags: flutter, dart, generics

```
abstract class BaseClass {
   String get propertyA;
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
   @override
   String propertyA = "SomeTextHere";
}

abstract class BaseRepo<T extends BaseClass> {
    T someMethod() {
     // how do I access ChildClass propertyA in here ???
    }
}

class ChildRepo extends BaseRepo<ChildClass> { 
}
```

base on the code above, how do I access ChildClass (inherited) property or method from BaseRepo generic ?

Thanks

EDIT:
In Java i could do this by something like this :

```
<T> void someMethod(Class<T> aClass) {
    T entity = aClass.newInstance();
    entity.getPropertyA(); // this will returned inherited property value
}
```

to call the method in Java, I could pass child class like this :
someMethod(ChildClass.class);

so, I'm looking a similar solution

Comment: I don't understand your question. BaseRepo inherits from neither BaseClass nor ChildClass, it should not have such a property.

Comment: it will be inherited and the inherited instance of BaseRepo will call out someMethod().

Comment: But your BaseRepo *does not have* a property "propertyA". It does nto inherit from either class. So... the answer is you *cannot* access this property there, because it does nto exist there. It only exists in BaseClass und ChildClass.

Comment: added a childrepo sample declaration

Comment: Okay... even ChildRepo does not have a property of that type, since *it does not inherit* from either ChildClass or BaseClass. Maybe you can add an example of what you want to do?

Comment: @nvoigt I did this before with Java, I added sample code for java

Comment: @nvoigt T in ChildRepo is ChildClass right? so someMethod() in BaseRepo should be able to instantiate T and get it's property

Comment: You'd call `someObject.someMethod()` the same way you would from any other code: you check  `if (someObject is ChildClass)` first.  If `someObject` is a local variable, its type will be promoted automatically if the condition is true.  If it's a non-local variable, the `if` body would need to do `(someObject as ChildClass).someMethod()`.

Comment: Regarding your Java example: for equivalent Dart code, you'd need to pass a callback that returns a `ChildClass`: `void someMethod<T extends ChildClass>(T Function() newInstance) { T entity = newInstance(); entity.getPropertyA(); }`

Comment: @jamesdlin your solution works, the one with passing T Function() newInstance ...